# How should I make this Navbar more responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to design a website and want it to be responsive.
But I do not want to use Bootstrap because of the amount of time it needs to load.
My navbar works just fine (I'll change the colors and everything later).
But when I scale it down to a mobile-size a button from the navbar slides under the others.

```css
body {
  background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #000000 0%, #545454 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
}

#backtohome {
  font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 60px;
  background: transparent;
  color: white
}

#home {
  font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
  margin-left: 2%;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: transparent;
  color: white
}

#discord {
  font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
  margin-left: 2%;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: transparent;
  color: white
}

#shop {
  font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
  margin-left: 2%;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: transparent;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <button id="backtohome" href="home.html">QsAGaming</button>
  <button id="home" href="home.html">Home</button>
  <button id="discord" href="home.html">Discord</button>
  <button id="shop" href="home.html">Shop</button>
</nav>
<div class="footer">
  <p id="footertext">©2020, QsA</p>
</div>
```

I would appreciate it if you would help me with turning this into a better navbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for normal you make navbars with @media screen [Look here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav)

if you just want the text to be responsive you can make use of the

> vw-attribute

by adding for example 5vw, instead of 60px to your text it will orientate on the window size, so your css should look like:

```
 body {
  background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #000000 0%, #545454 100%) 0% 0% no- repeat padding-box;

}

#backtohome {
  font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 5vw;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;

}

#home {
  font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
  margin-left: 2%;
  font-size: 4vw;
  background: transparent;
  color: white
}

#discord {
  font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
  margin-left: 2%;
  font-size: 4vw;
  background: transparent;
  color: white
}

#shop {
  font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
  margin-left: 2%;
  font-size: 4vw;
  background: transparent;
  color: white
}
```

Comment: Please be careful with the code provided in the w3schools. The code they show has a really poor quality and is full of bad practices

Answer (score 2):

you can use Media Querys of css to make a simple responsive system.

```css
<style>

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
}


[class*="col-"] {
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .col-s-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-s-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-s-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-s-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-s-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-s-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-s-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-s-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-s-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-s-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-s-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-s-12 {width: 100%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
  .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
  .col-3 {width: 25%;}
  .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
  .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
  .col-6 {width: 50%;}
  .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
  .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
  .col-9 {width: 75%;}
  .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
  .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
  .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
</style>
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3 col-s-3 menu">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 col-s-9">
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 col-s-12">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So the good idea would be to hide the regular `nav` on mobile screen widths and replace it the mobile nav hiding under the hamburger button.

Read about `media queries`. It's going to be really handy :)

Take a look at these examples I found on the codepen.

https://codepen.io/ijaed/pen/ggmMqj

https://codepen.io/abdosteif/pen/bRoyMb?editors=1100

Media Queries in use:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

EDIT:
I have one more tip. Try to avoid styling by the `#`. Use `.` classes instead :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're after responsive web design, you're best off looking at some media queries:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

that's pretty normal fluid behaviour. If you want to make it "more" responsive you want to consider using breakpoints with @media and look for some save resolutions for mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Bootstrap, you can use something which is called

Media query 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

When you work with responsive design, I recommend you do in mobile first way.

```
/* css for mobile */


/*css for laptop */

@media only screen and (min-width:1024px){}
 /*css for desktop*/

@media only screen and (min-width:1370px){}
```

start your css your navbar for mobile screen size, and then just change little bit in media query for laptop.

for example so:

```
/*css for mobile*/
button{ width:100%;}

/*css for laptop*/ 
@media only screen and (min-width:1024px){
 button{width:50%};
}

/*css for desktop*/
 @media only screen and (min-width:1370px){
  button{width:25%};
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `em` instead of absolute value `px`.
Try this css code and see its result

```
 body {
background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #000000 0%, #545454 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
 font-size: 10px;
}


#backtohome {
font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
text-align: left;
font-size: 6em;
background: transparent;
color: white
}

#home {
font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
margin-left: 2%;
font-size: 3em;
background: transparent;
color: white
}

#discord {
font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
margin-left: 2%;
font-size: 3em;
background: transparent;
color: white
}

#shop {
font-family: 'Bangers', cursive;
margin-left: 2%;
font-size: 3em;
background: transparent;
color: white
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 567px){
  body {
    font-size: 5px;
  }
}
```